# Does WhatsApp use certificate pinning?

Tags: tls, mobile, desktop, certificate-pinning

Does WhatsApp use certificate pinning? I found a post by [Preatorian Security](https://www.praetorian.com/blog/whats-up-with-whatsapps-security-facebook-ssl-vulnerabilities) from February 2014 that points the lack of certificate pinning as a major security problem, and mentions:

> Update 02/21/2014: WhatsApp is actively working on adding SSL Pinning now

How can I investigate if they already implemented this feature on a given client? I'm interested in the Android and Mac (released yesterday) clients.

Comment: This might be a question for Whatsapp support.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Whatsapp uses Certificate Pinning. When I tried to analyze the Android app in january, it didn't accept my forged certificates (created with mitmproxy). I didn't invesigate this further and I might have missed something.

However, Whatsapp upgraded its encryption algorithms earlier this year and introduced **end-to-end encryption**, and therefore messages are now better encrypted than it would ever be possible with TLS.

Comment: Indeed, I had to patch the code to bypass certificate pinning

Comment: What about the Windows and Mac client apps?

Comment: @AK_ I have not looked at them, so I don't know.